# Unable to register device token to Salesforce user - iOS Hybrid app

Tags: ios, salesforce-sdk-hybrid, ionic

I am trying to send a message from Salesforce to iOS Mobile Device, for this I have chosen the Push Notification feature.
My application developed in the Hybrid Application(Cordova, Ionic, Angular).

For this, I have followed the steps below

1. I have created the Cordova Project
2. After, I installed the Salesforce Mobile SDK for getting the data from Salesforce.(https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin)
3. I installed the Push Notification Plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push)
4. I wrote the code for getting the Device Token from iOS Vendor.
5. Did connected app setup as mentioned in the implementation guide. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.pushImplGuide.meta/pushImplGuide/pns_overview.htm
6. wrote trigger to send the notification but notification is not sent to the device. However, I am able to test the push notification by sending directly to the device using device token via connected app. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.220.0.pushImplGuide.meta/pushImplGuide/connected_app_test_apns.htm

The problem is that the device token is not getting registered to Salesforce user. When I click "Mobile Push Registration" on user record, nothing shows up.

Comment: We are using the SalesForce Mobile SDK Hybrid Cordova Plugin directly and trying to push notification using the Ionic.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be much easier to wire everything up using the our Hybrid Project than using the Cordova plugin directly.  We recommend starting of by generating your app with our CLI forcehybrid and customizing from there but it is possible to add the Hybrid lib into an exiting project.

forcehybrid: https://www.npmjs.com/package/forcehybrid

Hybrid: https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-ios-hybrid

Push Notification Doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/push_using_ios.htm

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I am interested in the piece where a device token gets registered to a user in Salesforce. Do I need to write a code for that for a hybrid app?

Comment: The SDK has utility methods you can call that handle this. 
 Doc with code examples here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/push_ios_code.htm

Comment: Thanks, but I need steps for hybrid app.

Comment: Apologies, juggling too many things here is info for hybrid: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/push_hybrid_code.htm

Comment: Hi Brandon, I did this. But i still dont see the device registered in salesforce.